# The whole world doesn't take me seriously. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> The whole world doesn't take me seriously, saying I follow no logic,
>
> even though I'm wise enough to calculate things most cannot.
>
> I've been here for a long time, even more than all my cousins,
>
> and still I'm sure you'd find me delicious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Pi

The whole world doesn't take me seriously, saying I follow no logic,

> No pattern to its digits

even though I'm wise enough to calculate things most cannot.

> Only way to accurately determine lots of stuff

I've been here for a longtime, even more than all my cousins,

> Discovered before *e* and other irrational numbers

and still I'm sure you'd find me delicious.

> Mmmmm... pie...

Answer (score 6):

My guess is

> Light

---

The whole world doesn't take me seriously, saying I follow no logic,

> Quantum mechanics (The study of subatomic particles like photons of light) is very confusing. It doesn't follow the logic of previously believed physics.

even though I'm wise enough to calculate things most cannot.

> Quantum computers, using qubits, can calculate things that regular computers can not.

I've been here for a longtime, even more than all my cousins,

> Light, as a form of energy, can never be created or destroyed from nothing (As stated by the [Third Law of Thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics)). Thus light, as any form of energy, always has (and always will) exist.

and still I'm sure you'd find me delicious.

> This is one that light doesn't really fit. Maybe light is quantum (a minimal amount), and [all food is good in moderation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=All+food+is+good+in+moderation), or a minimal amount.

Comment: This  is not the answer I was thinking about, but still could fit into the riddle. The last clue could relate to *light food*, which is how *healty* or *diet* food is often refered.

I love when people come up with alternative answers to riddles! +1!!!

Comment: Could also be a reference to light being used in photosynthesis by plants - turned into food, some might say.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> Noodles

The whole world doesn't take me seriously, saying I follow no logic,

> Fried pasta, does it make sense? In theory not!

even though I'm wise enough to calculate things most cannot.

> [Moebius noodles](http://naturalmath.com/thebook/) is a book. It may be a reference to [Quipu](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quipu) too, an ancient method of calculus.

I've been here for a longtime, even more than all my cousins,

> Noodles are older than spaghetti, they say.

and still I'm sure you'd find me delicious.

> They're delicious indeed!

Comment: This is silly! :-P

Comment: @randal'thor I was looking for an original answer and found one that fits surprisingly well.

Comment: I won't DV, but others might... BTW, congrats on breaking 7k! And don't take it personally when I put d'alar'cop ahead of you in rep again tomorrow - I'm just repaying bounties he [gave me](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/is-it-fair-to-transfer-3000-rep-to-a-friend) ages ago, so it's nothing to do with beating you :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Absolutely no problem, feel free to give him as many rep points as you want, I'm here to have fun, it's not a race!

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question has been answered, I would have said:

> Fungus

The whole world doesn't take me seriously, saying I follow no logic,

> It's neither a plant, an animal, nor a mineral. It's an entirely different classification of organism.

even though I'm wise enough to calculate things most cannot.

> Fungus was used to calculate the optimal routes of Tokyo's rail system (www.wired.com/2010/01/slime-mold-grows-network-just-like-tokyo-rail-system/)

I've been here for a long time, even more than all my cousins,

> Check out the [list of longest-living organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_longest-living_organisms), of which fungal colonies are among the oldest. According to [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwLviP7KaAc) by Paul Stamets, a renouned mycologist, fungus was what kept the earth and it's ecology alive during *all* of the earth's major extinction periods. It can be argued that nearly all life on earth evolved from fungus.

and still I'm sure you'd find me delicious.

> Last, but not least, who doesn't enjoy a great tasting portobello mushroom now again?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like it could be

> Time

Considering:

> the words "long time" were merged to "longtime"

The whole world doesn't take me seriously, saying I follow no logic,

> People waste their life not taking their time seriously. Some days seem to go fast and some slow, giving the appearance of not following any logic

even though I'm wise enough to calculate things most cannot.

> Time can be used to calculate a lot of things that we couldn't calculate without its existence

I've been here for a longtime, even more than all my cousins,

> Time has been here since the beginning of time... :P

and still I'm sure you'd find me delicious.

> I am sure anyone would be happy to eat up any extra time given to them

Comment: There were a few other typos now edited out, so this may not be significant. Also, how does it fit the _rest_ of the riddle?

Comment: Sorry, still constructing the rest of it. This was my guess regardless of that typo, it was just the deciding factor for me posting the answer

Comment: It seems to fit perfectly except the last line...

Comment: @randal'thor I was hoping it was metaphorical

Comment: Sorry for the typos.